# Carregar conteúdo em uma DIV usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5, ajax

Preciso carregar a pagina video.html na div com id video usando JavaScript.
Tenho o seguinte script:

```
function video() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "video.html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("#video").html(html);
        },
    });
}
```

E o seguinte HTML:

```
 <div id="video">

</div>
<br/>
    <button onclick="video()">Carregar</button>
```

Mas quando clico no botão "carregar" nada acontece.

Comment: Verificou se está entrando na função video ao clicar no botão? Se sim, verifique se está entrando na função success do ajax. Para acessar a página você está dando 2 cliques no .html e executando a função ou está acessando via http? Eu acho que esta requisição ajax, desta forma como está, só funciona via http. Implemente o método error do ajax para ver a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Deve estara contecendo algum erro, se estiver usando o Chrome, aperte F12 e poste aqui o erro que esta dando. provavelmente deve ser erro de XMLHttpRequest

Comment: E qual o conteúdo que tem  dentro do arquivo video.html?

Comment: o que acontece se no ready vc colocar alert(html)? A página video.html está na mesma pasta que a página executada? Vc também pode testar usando <button onclick="video();window.open('video.html')"> para ver se ela está carregando corretamente.  Se ela estiver, tente substituir a tag div por uma embed

Comment: Você importou a biblioteca jQuery? Vc não precisa fazer dessa forma há maneiras melhores de carregar um vídeo dinamicamente.

Answer (score 1):

Há maneiras melhores de fazer isso, dá uma olhada aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video.

Também tem essa API que pode te ajudar com inserção de vídeos:
http://www.videojs.com/

**Obs:** *caso o vídeo seja do youtube, você não vai conseguir fazer isso mesmo.*
 
Mas para um vídeo embutido na html, tente chamar seu método dessa forma:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('button').on('click', function() {
       $("#video").load("video.html");
   });
});
```

E no seu corpo do HTML:

```
 <div id="video"><!-- //aqui seu video --></div>
 <br />
 <button>Carregar</button>
```

Se o vídeo for do youtube, você pode carregar ele em um iframe, passando a URL no click do botão.